# In grouped data, how to arrange the rows of only *some* columns by the values of a column, while keeping the rest of columns untouched?

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I have data in long format, grouped by one variable. I'm trying to sort/arrange rows by the order of values in a certain column, by group. The thing is, I want to apply this sorting on the rows in *some* columns, while the other columns should remain untouched. I've tried using `mutate(across(...))` to operate on the columns of interest, but got an error.

### Example Data

```r
set.seed(2020)

df <-
  data.frame(name = rep(c("john", "bob", "ralph"), each = 8),
           test_scores = sample(30:100, size = 24),
           year_taken = sample(1993:2020, size = 24),
           dont_touch_this_col = LETTERS[1:24])

> df
##     name test_scores year_taken dont_touch_this_col
## 1   john          74       2002                   A
## 2   john          72       1993                   B
## 3   john          98       2007                   C
## 4   john          87       2014                   D
## 5   john          95       2001                   E
## 6   john          54       2008                   F
## 7   john          64       1998                   G
## 8   john          53       2020                   H
## 9    bob          79       2019                   I
## 10   bob          62       2012                   J
## 11   bob          83       2009                   K
## 12   bob          36       2000                   L
## 13   bob          37       2018                   M
## 14   bob          50       2004                   N
## 15   bob          85       2013                   O
## 16   bob          42       1994                   P
## 17 ralph          63       1997                   Q
## 18 ralph          34       2010                   R
## 19 ralph          33       1996                   S
## 20 ralph          48       2006                   T
## 21 ralph          77       2016                   U
## 22 ralph          52       2017                   V
## 23 ralph          82       2015                   W
## 24 ralph          47       2003                   X
```

---

**Grouping by `name` and arranging by `year_taken` is easy**

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(year_taken, .by_group = TRUE)


## # A tibble: 24 x 4
## # Groups:   name [3]
##    name  test_scores year_taken dont_touch_this_col
##    <chr>       <int>      <int> <chr>              
##  1 bob            42       1994 P                  
##  2 bob            36       2000 L                  
##  3 bob            50       2004 N                  
##  4 bob            83       2009 K                  
##  5 bob            62       2012 J                  
##  6 bob            85       2013 O                  
##  7 bob            37       2018 M                  
##  8 bob            79       2019 I                  
##  9 john           72       1993 B                  
## 10 john           64       1998 G
```

**But I want to do this by-group arranging while keeping `dont_touch_this_col` untouched**

One unsuccessful attempt was to use `mutate(across())` to specify (or exclude) specific variables:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(across(-dont_touch_this_col, arrange, year_taken, .by_group = TRUE))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`. x no applicable method for
> 'arrange_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')" i
> Input `..1` is `across(-dont_touch_this_col, arrange, year_taken, .by_group = TRUE)`. i The error occurred in group 1: name = "bob".

So how can I arrange grouped data by a column of interest (here it's `year_taken`) while keeping one (or more columns) out of the operation?

Comment: perhaps you really want to be using `sort`? The `arrange` function takes as its first argument `.data`, or in other words, it does not arrange a vector of numbers/values the way `sort` does, but rather operates on a data frame. Furthermore, when used (properly), `arrange` does not break the row-dependencies. In other words, if you rearrange the order of the rows of one column, you must take the rows of all of the other columns along for the ride. For `arrange` you sort the whole data frame, but on the basis of the rank/order of the values in the column supplied to the 2nd arg of `arrange`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this. You can use `bind_cols()` to add the variables you want untouched and excluding them from the sorting task. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(2020)
#Data
df <-
  data.frame(name = rep(c("john", "bob", "ralph"), each = 8),
             test_scores = sample(30:100, size = 24),
             year_taken = sample(1993:2020, size = 24),
             dont_touch_this_col = LETTERS[1:24])
#Code
newdf <- df %>% select(-dont_touch_this_col) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(year_taken, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  bind_cols(df %>% select(dont_touch_this_col))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 24 x 4
# Groups:   name [3]
   name  test_scores year_taken dont_touch_this_col
   <fct>       <int>      <int> <fct>              
 1 bob            83       1998 A                  
 2 bob            79       2002 B                  
 3 bob            58       2003 C                  
 4 bob            63       2005 D                  
 5 bob            85       2013 E                  
 6 bob            45       2018 F                  
 7 bob            37       2019 G                  
 8 bob            95       2020 H                  
 9 john           65       1999 I                  
10 john           57       2004 J                  
# ... with 14 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
cbind(df[with(df, order(name, year_taken)), 
     c('name', 'test_scores', 'year_taken')], df['dont_touch_this_col'])
```